# Application runtime exceptions are not being sent to errorChannel or ServiceActivator not able to listen on to errorChannel

Tags: error-handling, spring-integration, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

After listening on a kafka topic using @StreamListener, upon RuntimeException, global erroChannel or topic specific errorChannel (topic.group.errors) not receiving any error message. @ServiceActivator not receiving anything.

> POM Dependencies :  Greenwich.RELEASE

```
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-schema</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

> application.properties

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=input
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.group=myGroup
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.useNativeDecoding=true

spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.input.consumer.enableDlq=true
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.input.consumer.dlqName=input_deadletter
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.input.consumer.autoCommitOnError=true
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.input.consumer.keySerde=io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerde
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.input.consumer.valueSerde=io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerde

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=output
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.content-Type=application/*+avro
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.useNativeEncoding=true
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.errorChannelEnabled=true
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.output.producer.keySerde=io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerde
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.output.producer.valueSerde=io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerde

spring.cloud.stream.schemaRegistryClient.endpoint.schema.avro.schema-locations=classpath:avro/*.avsc

spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.brokers=localhost

spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.default.key.serde=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.default.value.serde=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.commit.interval.ms=1000
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8082

spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.application-id=myGroup
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.serdeError=sendtodlq
```

I can see in the logs that service activator is registered and subscribed to the error Channels.
All the streams are stopped and going to shutdown mode once runtime exception occurs.

```
Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
org.springframework.integration.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter - Registering MessageChannel input.myGroup.errors
org.springframework.integration.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter - Located managed bean 'org.springframework.integration:type=MessageChannel,name="input-myGroup.errors"': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.integration:type=MessageChannel,name="input.myGroup.errors"] org.springframework.integration.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter - Registering MessageChannel errorChannel
org.springframework.integration.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter - Located managed bean 'org.springframework.integration:type=MessageChannel,name=errorChannel': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.integration:type=MessageChannel,name=errorChannel]
org.springframework.integration.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter - Registering MessageChannel nullChannel
org.springframework.integration.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter - Located managed bean 'org.springframework.integration:type=MessageChannel,name=nullChannel': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.integration:type=MessageChannel,name=nullChannel]
 org.springframework.integration.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter - Registering MessageHandler errorLogger
org.springframework.integration.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter - Located managed bean 'org.springframework.integration:type=MessageHandler,name=errorLogger,bean=internal': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.integration:type=MessageHandler,name=errorLogger,bean=internal]
 org.springframework.integration.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter - Registering MessageHandler myTopicListener.error.serviceActivator
org.springframework.integration.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter - Located managed bean 'org.springframework.integration:type=MessageHandler,name=myTopicListener.error.serviceActivator,bean=endpoint': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.integration:type=MessageHandler,name=myTopicListener.error.serviceActivator,bean=endpoint]
org.springframework.integration.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter - Registering MessageHandler myTopicListener.errorGlobal.serviceActivator
 org.springframework.integration.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter - Located managed bean 'org.springframework.integration:type=MessageHandler,name=myTopicListener.errorGlobal.serviceActivator,bean=endpoint': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.integration:type=MessageHandler,name=myTopicListener.errorGlobal.serviceActivator,bean=endpoint]
org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - No @KafkaListener annotations found on bean type: class org.springf
```

```
    @SendTo(MyStreams.OUTPUT)
    public KStream<Key, MyEntity> process(KStream<Key, Envelope> myStreamObject) {

        return myStreamObject.mapValues(this::transform);
    }

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "input.myGroup.errors") //channel name 'input.myGroup.errors'
    public void error(Message<?> message) {
        System.out.println("Handling ERROR:  " + message);
 }

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "errorChannel")
    public void errorGlobal(Message<?> message) {
        System.out.println("Handling ERROR: GLOBAL " + message);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kafka **streams** binder is not based on `MessageChannel`s so there is no `Message<?>` to send to the error channel.

The standard kafka binder is a `MessageChannelBinder` and supports the error channel.

With Kafka Streams you have to implement your own error handling.

Comment: I was waiting for your verdict on this Gary, Thanks. May be it would be great if Spring cloud streams documentation explicitly clarifies this.

Comment: I have enabled DLQ for serde errors and it is successfully forwarding the failed messages to the DLQ. Is there any recommended way to send the application errors to the same DLQ?

Comment: Don't ask new questions in comments; it doesn't help people find answers. Ask a new question.